# I'm getting same values on this query using CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql

i'm very new on mysql and i'm trying to get some values on this query using the CASE WHEN validation

```
SELECT u.id, u.username as "Nombre", 
       tm.name as "Facturable", 
  CASE tm.name      
  WHEN tm.name = "facturable_actividad" and tm.value= 1 then SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.start_time, t.end_time)) END AS "HH",
       tm.name as "No facturable",
  CASE tm.name
  WHEN "facturable_actividad" AND tm.value= 0 THEN SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.start_time, t.end_time)) END as "NO HH"
FROM  kimai2_users u
JOIN kimai2_timesheet t
ON u.id = t.user
JOIN kimai2_timesheet_meta tm
ON t.id = tm.timesheet_id
GROUP BY t.user;
```

Basically i'm saying that i want to create a new row called "**HH**" and inside it i say if "**facturable_actividad**" is 1 then do a sum a get X result. Else i have other row "**NO HH**" where i do the same but "**facturable_actividad**" is 0.

I get this:

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoq7p.png)

As you can see i get the same values for **HH** and **NO HH** (hh means billable), the **NO HH** should be much less than HH and not the same !

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer to you question is that when you write

```
CASE tm.name      
WHEN tm.name = "facturable_actividad" and tm.value= 1
```

you are effectively checking whether `tm.name = (tm.name = "facturable_actividad" and tm.value= 1)` which is different than checking only the part in brackets.

If you are checking a single column for certain values, it makes sense to write something like

```
CASE mycolumn
 WHEN "a" then 0
 WHEN "b" then 1
 ELSE 2
END
```

This checks whether mycolumn="a" then whether mycolumn="b" as you would expect.

But if you want to do multiple conditions as part of a `WHEN`, you probably don't want to write anything after the `CASE` part.

```
CASE
 WHEN mycolumn="a" and mycolumn2="b" then 1
 WHEN mycolumn="c" and mycolumn2="d" then 2
 ELSE 3
END
```

As you would expect, this checks the first condition (`mycolumn="a" and mycolumn2="b"`) then the second condition (`mycolumn="c" and mycolumn2="d"`)

Since you are checking multiple columns in the same `WHEN`, you probably don't want to write tm.name after the case. So instead of `CASE tm.name WHEN [condition]` you simply write `CASE WHEN [condition]`. The entire condition is spelled out the `WHEN` part.

```
SELECT u.id, u.username as "Nombre", 
       tm.name as "Facturable", 
  CASE      
  WHEN tm.name = "facturable_actividad" and tm.value= 1 then SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.start_time, t.end_time)) END AS "HH",
       tm.name as "No facturable",
  CASE
  WHEN tm.name = "facturable_actividad" AND tm.value= 0 THEN SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.start_time, t.end_time)) END as "NO HH"
FROM  kimai2_users u
JOIN kimai2_timesheet t
ON u.id = t.user
JOIN kimai2_timesheet_meta tm
ON t.id = tm.timesheet_id
GROUP BY t.user;
```

Although I think the above answers your question, I suspect what you are really going for is:

```
 SELECT u.id, u.username as "Nombre", 
       tm.name as "Facturable", 
  SUM(CASE     
  WHEN tm.name = "facturable_actividad" and tm.value= 1 then TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.start_time, t.end_time) END) AS "HH",
       tm.name as "No facturable",
  SUM(CASE 
  WHEN tm.name = "facturable_actividad" AND tm.value= 0 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.start_time, t.end_time) END) as "NO HH"
FROM  kimai2_users u
JOIN kimai2_timesheet t
ON u.id = t.user
JOIN kimai2_timesheet_meta tm
ON t.id = tm.timesheet_id
GROUP BY t.user;
```

Here, the `SUM` wraps the `CASE` statement instead of the other way around. I am making an assumption about what you're trying to do here.